# Junit testing stack pop

Tags: java, junit, stack

I am trying to use Junit it test if my stack is working properly. I am getting the output:

```
testPopEmptyStack(StackTesting.TestJunitStack): null
false
```

However I expect to get an output `true` because in my stack class. If `pop()` a stack that has no `nodes` in it, I wanted it to `throw new EmptyStackException()`.

stack class:

```
public class Stack {
    Node top;
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Node> stack = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public boolean checkEmpty() {
        if (count == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Node getTop() {
        if (count > 0) {
            return top;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void pop() {
        if (count > 0) {
            stack.remove(0);
            count--;
        }
        else {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }

    public void push(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        stack.add(node);
        count++;
    }

    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

TestJunitStack.java:

```
public class TestJunitStack extends TestCase{

    static Stack emptystack = new Stack();

    @Test(expected = EmptyStackException.class)
    public void testPopEmptyStack() {
        emptystack.pop();
    }
}
```

TestRunnerStack.java:

```
public class TestRunnerStack {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunitStack.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

`static` removed from `testPopEmptyStack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `static` from here

```
public static void testPopEmptyStack() {
...
```

Comment: the output is the same =[

Comment: try my simplified test     @Test(expected = EmptyStackException.class)
    public void testPopEmptyStack() {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }

Comment: hmm strange, it has the same output. I like this test case

Comment: fyi: my output with this test is "true"

Comment: crap... what could be causing this

Comment: remove "extends TestCase"

Comment: AWESOME! I'm not sure what testcase does actually.. i was following a tutorial =[